# Yii, Fatal error: Call to a member function addComment() on a non-object

Tags: php, yii, fatal-error

I am fairly new to Yii and while trying to make a blog application of my own I made this function to add a comment to my post.

However, I have done everything according to theory but still am getting a :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addComment() on a non-object in /htdocs/blog/protected/controllers/PostController.php on line 63
```

My Post.php model class has this function :

```
public function addComment($comment){
        $comment->tbl_post_id = $this->id;
        return $comment->save();
    }
```

And my PostController.php has these two function, one for creating the comment and the other one for altering the view file.

```
public function actionView($id)
   {
       $post=$this->loadModel($id);
       $comment=$this->createComment($post);
       $this->render('view',array(
         'model'=>$post,
            'comment'=>$comment,
￼)); }

    protected function createComment($post)
   {
     $comment=new Comment;
     if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
     {
       $comment->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
       if($post->addComment($comment)) // **This is line 63**
       {
         Yii::app()->user->setFlash('commentSubmitted',"Your comment has been added." );
         $this->refresh();
       }
}
     return $comment;
   }
```

So logically I am calling the member function addComment inside the Post Model class using $post->addComment, and all the member functions of a model are initialized right? And logicaly shouldn't this be correct right? However, I am getting the above fatal error.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

P.S - I am sorry if I am doing something really stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$post` isn't an object since you don't declare it anywhere

```
 protected function createComment($issue)
 {
   $comment=new Comment;
   if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
   {
     $comment->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
     if($post->addComment($comment)) // **This is line 63**
     {
       Yii::app()->user->setFlash('commentSubmitted',"Your comment has been added." );
       $this->refresh();
     }
   }
   return $comment;
 }
```

on line 63 he's searching for a variable named `$post` that does not exist. You have to create it or load from db like you're doing into your `actionView()`

```
$post=$this->loadModel($id);
```

Obviously for load it, you need `$id` that has to be passed to your `createComment()` function

Comment: Oh ok!! Got it thank you tons.. I know it was a stupid mistake for sure.

Comment: However I had a small doubt, the thing is why is the $comment variable working as it is a reference to the model class of Comment.? I have initialized it anywhere in the class??

Comment: `$comment=new Comment;` you have initialized it on the first line of `createComment()` method

Comment: No that is in the Controller class, i.e. PostController.php not in the model class i.e. Post.php, but still it is working how come?

Comment: @SankalpSingha: without more code, is difficult to understand what you're asking for

Answer (score 0):

You have **addComment**() method in **Post** Model Class. So, You can handle this method by the Object of **Post** Model class from any of your controller.

Your declaration

```
 $post->addComment($comment)
```

is Correct but there is no **$post** object. So Just create instance of Post Model as

```
$post=new Post();
```

Finally your code should be like

```
 if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
 {
    $comment->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
    $post=new Post(); 

    if($post->addComment($comment)) // **This is line 63**
    {
       Yii::app()->user->setFlash('commentSubmitted',"Your comment has been added." );
       $this->refresh();
    }
 }
```